# Pass variable to another component and display it in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I need to show the user variable in the Menu Component (h6) but the user variable is in another component

The user variable is const user = this.props.auth
I want to show it in the typography h6

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    onLogoutClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.logoutUser()
   }  

render() {
    const {user} = this.props.auth
    return(
        <div>
            <Menu User={user}></Menu>             
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default function Menu(props) {
const classes = useStyles()
const theme = useTheme()

const user = this.props.User
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>            
        <Typography variant='h6' noWrap>
            Welcome, {user}
        </Typography>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can use `params`. [Here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-url-parameters/) is a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
<Typography variant='h6' noWrap>Welcome, {user}</Typography>
```

You have to close the curly bracket as show above and it should work fine.